# How do I change screen resolution in Solaris 10?

Tags: gnome, solaris, solaris-10

I am using Sun Java Desktop System for Solaris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the platform:

- x86: [xrandr](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2#Using__.24_xrandr) (runtime, for the life of the session), create/edit xorg.conf for future sessions
- sparc: [fbconfig](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5166/fbconfig-1m.html#scrolltoc)

Comment: I am using x86. I will try it soon.